# How to create automated test for BOOT_COMPLETED and USER_PRESENT receivers using device farm?

Tags: android, automated-tests

I've reached a stage in development where I need to validate my application on real devices. I've never used a device farm and for this reason I do not know which one would suit me.

Two crucial application features are directly linked to the BOOT_COMPLETED and USER_PRESENT Receivers, so I should be able to reboot the device (at this point a service will start automatically and I will have to validate if it is running). Also, for the USER_PRESENT Receiver I should be able to perform the blocking and unlocking screen actions to perform some validations.

Is it possible to do that?

Edit: My idea is to test the receivers without calling the `onReceive` method directly, because some triggers like USER_PRESENT doesn't get called properly in some API levels

Answer (score 2):

At AWS Device Farm, we don't support the rebooting of devices during a customer test. However, it should be possible for you to test your lock screen test on our devices so long as your test is able to interact with the phone while it is locked. This isn't possible in iOS, but is possible in some cases with Android.

Thanks